# Nested queries with pool.query in Typescript and MySQL

Tags: typescript, express

After a few hours of reviewing and trying there is no other choice but to ask. I am developing a backend in Node.Js Express.Js and Typescript. I have it pretty organized but now I try to list all the rows of a Recipes table (recipe_table) but in an array that also contains its Ingredients (mix_table). I was able to make it for a single recipe. This is the closest I've ever been.

```
public async read(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void>{
await pool.query('SELECT * FROM recipe_table', (err: any, recipes: any) => {
    if (!err) {
        let result: { recipe: any; mix: any; }[] = [];
        console.log(result);
        for (let recipe of recipes){
            pool.query('SELECT * FROM mix_table WHERE recipe_id = ?', [recipe.recipe_id], (err: any, mix: any) => {
                result.push({ recipe, mix });
            });
        }
        res.status(200).json({ result });
    } else {
        res.status(500).json({ err, message: "Ha ocurrido un error en su peticion" });
    }
});
```

}

Greetings for everyone and thanks in advance.